# JQuery and set data more permanently

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery

Hi
I used jquery in my application and I have a problem but I think it is necessarly to look at this code :

```
        $("#btnAddToBasket").click(function () {
            var id = $("#ProductIDAtBasket").text();
            var count = $("#BasketAddedValueText").val();
            //ajax request
            $.ajax({ type: "Post",
                url: "Services/NewE_ShopServices.asmx" + "/" + "GetPrice",
                data: "{" + "count" + ":" + count + ", goodcode : " + id + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: AjaxSucceeded,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
        });

        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            var res = result.d;
            res = res.split(';');
            $("#spanFinalPrice").text(res[2]);
            $("#spanAbsolutePrice").text(res[3]);
            $("#spanDiscount").text(res[4]);
            $("#spanCount").text(res[1]);
            $("#AddBasketDiv").hide("slow");
        }

        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }
```

As you can see at the following there is ajax send method to web service I get the values and put results using ajaxsucceeded method into the page it works fine and suitable but my problem is that it is basket viewer and I want to be more permanent for example in this page when you go to other page and back to it the contains will be omitted I can use session and cookies in the webservice class but how I can read from jQuery code? what is solution is there any other solution ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: It sounds like your problem is not with jQuery, but with how you have architected your server side code.  Not really possible to answer this with the data you have supplied.

Comment: it is so simple an hashtable object serialize by json in web service method and it gets back to page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add another ajax method to my jquery script and put some sever side property and set them by ajax method that was easiest.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly, you are adding things to a basket, but they are not persisting on other pages? I.E, you add a product to your basket, and then move to another page and the item is not in the basket?

If so you need to check a couple of things:

1. How are you storing the basket on the server side. Do you put the items in Session?
2. Are you reading from that basket to pre-populate the basket in a state before you add items in?